# I have a routine for moving motors with encoders at a distance, but I want to be able to interrupt that routine

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt

I am using Arduino Serial1 to read commands:

```
void loop()
{
  if (Serial1.available())
  {
    int commandNumber = Serial1.parseInt();
    switch (commandNumber)
    {
      case 0: TestStraightMovement(1); break;
      case 1: TestStraightMovement(-1); break;
    }
  }
}
```

I am attaching the interrupt when my code enters in `TestStraightMovement`. Then
I want when I receive info to the Rx pin to interrupt that command, detach interrupt and return back to the main loop for reading another command. But the interrupt is called before my command even enters.

Comment: The code you provided does not show any interrupt handler? Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how an interrupt works and that's not what an interrupt is for.  An interrupt will run some code and then return the execution to wherever it was when the interrupt occurred.  You use an interrupt so that something happens in the middle of the execution of another function but then goes back and finishes that function.

If you want to terminate that function and go back to the main loop then you don't need an interrupt.  You just need to rewrite that function so that it checks for whatever input in a non-blocking fashion and can exit at an appropriate time.  Since you didn't post much of the code it is pretty impossible to give you any hints on how to do that.